# Avoid duplicate Webpack chunk

Tags: javascript, webpack, import

I'm trying to inject into the Webpack project, and am faced with the following situation. I have two entry points: `about` and `feedback`.

`about` imports `feedback`, while both `about` and `feedback` are connected to the page. As a result, the code from `feedback` is duplicated twice.

Question: How can I import `feedback` into `about` without including code? That is, to make Webpack import a module from another file.

I know about `optimization.splitChunks`. In my situation it does not fit. The fact is that I may have many components that are connected on different pages (Maybe several at once). Combining them into one chunk and connecting everywhere is not desirable.

Comment: That is *exactly* the use case of the SplitChunksPlugin as explained in [Webpack's docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prevent-duplication) on preventing duplication. What is wrong?

Comment: SplitChunksPlugin or optimization.splitChunks take out duplicate chunks in a separate file. And I need so that I can import an already existing chunk from another file, without including the code in the current file.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an additional option called optimization in your webpack config file

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  optimization: {
    mergeDuplicateChunks: false,
  }
  ...
}
```

Please find the documentation regarding the same here - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationmergeduplicatechunks